# Как сделать чтобы словарь генерировал кнопки телеграм боту telebot

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot

Есть словарь:

```
dictionary = {
    'ua': {
        'lang': 'Українська',
    },
    'ru': {
        'lang': 'Русский',  
    },

    'eng': {
        'lang': 'English',
    },
}
```

И нужно чтобы после "if message.text ==" генерировался с каждего языка 'lang', кнопка

```
@client.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == :
            client.send_message(chat_id, "Test")
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, что вы хотите, обьясните конкретнее

Comment: Что бы кнопка генерировалась сама после нажатия

Comment: Что ж, удачи вам с этой непонятной задачей